# Hyperref and Subfigure warning

Tags: hyperref, memoir, subfloats

I am using the `memoir` class, with the `hyperref` package. At one point, I have a couple subfigures:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering     %%% not \center
\subbottom[]{\label{fig:turtled}\includegraphics[height=4cm]{graphics/turtled.png}}
\subbottom[]{\label{fig:capsized}\includegraphics[height=4cm]{graphics/capsized.png}}
\subbottom[]{\label{fig:mast-lift}\includegraphics[height=4cm]{graphics/mast-lift.png}}
\caption{(a) A turtled vessel being brought to the capsized position. (b) A capsized vessel being brought to the upright position. (c) The assisted mast-lift technique.}
\label{fig:righting}
\end{figure}
```

using the `subbottom` command. I then reference them later in the code:

```
... shown in \autoref{fig:mast-lift}.
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting a warning about this that I can't seem to figure out:

```
Package hyperref Warning: No autoref name for `subfigure' on input line ###
```

Anyone have an idea on how to get rid of this warning?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `\autoref` instead of `\ref`?

Comment: @Mario Hmm, you're actually right. After a little experimentation, I've found that the best method for my purpose is to define a custom \hyperref that incorporates \ref*.

Comment: @Jordan glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply provide the missing definition (I suppressed parts of the original code that were not relevant here):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\providecommand\subfigureautorefname{Subfigure}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering     %%% not \center
\subbottom[]{\label{fig:turtled}\includegraphics[height=4cm]{graphics/turtled.png}}
\end{figure}
\autoref{fig:turtled}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.